# Reverse Engineer JSBin: Why are they using iframe to run the given code instead of 'eval'?

Tags: javascript, iframe, xss, jsbin

I'm reverse engineering on how JSBIN is running the JavaScript and outputting to Console.  It seems that they are creating an IFRAME and put the code that user entered.  Override 'console.' (ex console.log) to capture the output or something similar (still reading the code).

My question is why are they running in iframe instead of simply running the 'eval' method.  I'm sure they must have good reason.  Is it because of XSS attack? If so what prevents XSS from happening by running the code in iframe?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Because eval is dangerous and error prone, doing it in an iframe or a webworker mean it won't run in the current context and can't change content on the page but can still communicate thru callbacks.

Comment: look at their iframe settings

    iframe.setAttribute('sandbox', 'allow-modals allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts');

'allow-same-origin' will give the iframe the access to the parent right? I suppose I can filter out any javascript code that contains 'parent' or other harmful commands.  Not sure why they set the 'allow-same-origin' settings.

Comment: after further investigation. They are executing in iframe within another iframe...holy... this feels like inception level 3.  So it looks like JSBin still keeps the state of the code being run on parent Iframe and run the code under child iframe.  I've tried to access parent.parent.alert and it blocked it